# Android Latest latitude and longitude

Tags: android

I have written a code which will get the latest Latitude and Longitude on a press of a button. What I found when deployed on mobile is that it gives the last time the mobile had sync with tower and after few seconds when tried again it comes closer to actual Latitude and Longitude. How to get the latest co-ordinates after mobile gets sync with nearest tower ? Pl. help.

Code

```
buttonGetLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
         // Send SMS on only first Update
        sendSMS(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()); 


    } else {
        textLongitude.setText("Location not available");
        textLatitude.setText("Location not available");
    }

    }
});
```

Comment: what heve you tried so far?

Comment: Post your code for getting coordinates, please